# vscode docstrings not appearing properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, markdown, docstring

I have no idea why I am experiencing this issue. In past projects (On a different computer with a different OS) I have had no issues displaying docstrings. When I write a docstring, it should show something like this.

[image: Working docstring]

Instead, my docstrings are not being formatted properly, and I am getting the following.

[image: Incorrect Formatting]

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? I am using VScode, and don't think anything needs to be installed to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Visual Studio Code are you using on each machine? What version of the Python extension? What operating system?

Comment: @Chris I don't remember the details of the other machine unfortunately, other than the fact that I was running on Ubuntu (18.04?) and was on what I think at the time was the latest version of Python at the time (~3.6-3.7). I am now running on Mac OS. I was probably using 2019.8.0 when I was on my linux machine, and I am currently on python 3.7.5 with the 2019.10.4 extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your language server that will shift how the docstrings get rendered (e.g. went from Jedi to MPLS or vice-versa). You can  [the issue tracking improving docstring support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/38) to help prioritize that work to try and handle this sort of thing.